# Which datatype to use for System.Text.Json.JsonDocument

Tags: blazor

As I want to use jsonDocument in a different razor page (page2). I want AppState.json to hold data from jsonDocument, not sure which datatype to use.  Thank you.

Rite now it says cannot convert System.Text.Json.JsonDocument to string.

AppState.cs:

```
public string? json
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

page1.razor:

```
private IBrowserFile _loadedFile;
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{   
    _loadedFile = e.File;
    var utf8Json = _loadedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10); 
    try
    {
        var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(utf8Json);
        AppState.json = jsonDocument @* Which datatype should I be using *@                      
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

page2.razor:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Create", AppState.json);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property to:

```cs
public JsonDocument? json { get; set; }
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Text.Json;`.